# laravel5 CalendarController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5

I use calender from https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar,

when I call -  http://myla/nomer
i get error:

**Class App\Http\Controllers\CalendarController does not exist**
[image]

CalendarController.php

```
$events = [];

$events[] = \Calendar::event(
    'Event One', //event title
    false, //full day event?
    '2015-02-11T0800',//start time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
    '2015-02-12T0800', //end time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
    0 //optionally, you can specify an event ID
);

$events[] = \Calendar::event(
    "Valentine's Day", //event title
    true, //full day event?
    new \DateTime('2015-02-14'), //start time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
    new \DateTime('2015-02-14'), //end time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
    'stringEventId' //optionally, you can specify an event ID
);

$eloquentEvent = EventModel::first(); //EventModel implements MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Event

$calendar = \Calendar::addEvents($events) //add an array with addEvents
->addEvent($eloquentEvent, [ //set custom color fo this event
    'color' => '#800',])->setOptions([ //set fullcalendar options
    'firstDay' => 1])->setCallbacks([ //set fullcalendar callback options (will not be JSON encoded)
    'viewRender' => 'function() {alert("Callbacks!");}']);

return view('all_nom.blade.php', compact('calendar'));
```

my routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('nomer/{id}','nomerController@show' );
Route::get('nomer','CalendarController@index');
```

and all_nom.blade.php

```
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.css"/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
{!! $calendar->calendar() !!}
{!! $calendar->script() !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

and all files have permision 777.
Please help, where is error?

Comment: Have you tried using "CalendarController" as classname instead of just Calendar?

Answer (score 1):

Try: `\App\Calender` instead of `\Calender` in your `CalenderController` and your controller use `Calendar`, not `CalendarController`. Either change its name to `CalendarController` (recommended) or just use `Calendar` in your `routes.php`.

Comment: Thank u - it work , but i get error  'FatalErrorException in Calendar.php line 32: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\EventModel' not found'
<br> In app.php added string provider '        MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\ServiceProvider::class,' and how aliase

Comment: how aliase ''Calendar'    => MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Facades\Calendar::class,' . Where may be error ?

Comment: Have you added the appropriate `Service Provider` facades into your `app.php` file?

Comment: yes, how provider -  MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\ServiceProvider::class, and how aliases   -  'Calendar'    => MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Facades\Calendar::class.
Code here -  http://codebin.org/view/e5391bf7